# How does JS assign the prototype of a var after parsing it from JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

How does JS assign the prototype of a var after parsing it from JSON, does it just assign the base prototype such as Object or will there be no prototype at all? Will it remember the auto prototype?

```js
function Car(make, model, year) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
}

var auto = new Car('Honda', 'Accord', 1998);

console.log('auto instanceof Car:', auto instanceof Car);
// expected output: true

console.log('auto instanceof Object:', auto instanceof Object);
// expected output: true

// Commented this out because I doubt the implementation matters
//var newJSONObj = auto.toJSON(); 
var newJSONObj = JSON.stringify(auto);
console.log('as JSON:', newJSONObj);

newObj = JSON.parse(newJSONObj);

console.log('newObj instanceof Car:', newObj instanceof Car);
// expected output: ???????

console.log('newObj instanceof Object:', newObj instanceof Object);
// expected output: ???????
```

Comment: Why not just run it and see for yourself?

Comment: The answer: it doesn't.

Comment: `auto.toJSON` is not a function . What exactly you are trying to do here

Comment: object to json is JSON.stringify(obj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `JSON.stringify` on an object, javascript only stores some portion of the object: its properties and values. All the rest is lost. So when you recreate the object using `JSON.parse` it is a plain object.

The process of storing objects in a form that is good for transport and storage is called serialization. But as you can see, for custom objects that have non standard prototype chain and for example methods, all this can't be serialized. That's the one reason to ditch object oriented programming in favor of functional programming that uses POJOs and pure functions hence the state of an app can be easily serialized.